# Map object instance to 'this'?

Tags: c#, .net, object, reflection, reference

This is just a 'out-of-curiosity' question, so I can't provide a real world example based on a current problem, but a little dummy code should suffice. What I'm wondering is if there is a straight-forward (and especially fast) way to map an instance of an object to 'this' (a current instance of the exact same type, with access to private members etc.)

```
public class MyObject {
    public MyObject(MyObject other) {
        // of course, won't work
        this = other;
    }
}
```

All examples and how-to's I've seen take excessive use of reflection, even building up complete expression trees or using frameworks like Automapper, all with their own limitations when the idea seems 'fairly trivial'. Why isn't it just possible to copy over all pointers/references etc. from one place in memory to another, given that the allocated space etc. is exactly the same?

Comment: you can clone it using ISerializable

Comment: Because "copying" is a wholeheckofalot more complicated than you assume.  Suppose the class has a field of type List.  Do you copy the reference or do you create a new list and copy the elements into it?  And if you do the latter, do you copy the item references or do the item objects need to be copied as well?  What should happen with their fields?  What if you don't have enough access to do that correctly?  Try to solve this in the language and you'll get a C++ frankenlanguage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there isn't a straight forward way to do that for the own instance (this). And I imagine that copying the data from the other instance to this would suffice. What might be an alternative for you is work with a static instance, but this has some particularities if you need to work with more then one instance.

```
public class MyObject {


    private static MyObject _instance;

    public static MyObject Instance 
    {
        get { return _instance; }
        set { _instance  = value; }
    } }
```

PS: I wrote this post from my cell, so forgive me if you run into minor errors, as I wasn't able to test it before posting. I will update the post as soon as I'm able to test the code.

Answer (score 1):

If this was possible you´re simply referencing `other` by a new reference, but not copy its content to a new instance of `MyObject`. So your constructor would simply return a new reference to the already existing instance. What you need is a completely new instance of `MyObject`, don´t you? So you have to create one using one of its constructors. If you have a copy-constructor that achieves this you´re fine:

```
public class MyObject {
    public MyObject(MyObject other) {
        this.Prop1  = other.Prop1;
    }
}
```

Of course there are some shorter (but not neccesarily saver) appraoches - e.g. using reflection and simply copy all property values from one instance to another one. However basically you still end up creating a completely new instance by setting of of its members appropriately.

The reflection-code may look similar to this:

```
public class MyObject {
    public MyObject(MyObject other) {
        var props = typeof(MyObject).GetProperties();
        foreach(var p in props)
        {
            p.SetValue(this, p.GetValue(other));
        }
    }
}
```

However this only applies to the public properties, you have to do this with the fields and the private or internal members also.

Comment: If I'd need a completely new instance depends on the use-case, I think. Let's say I've got a configuration system based on a strongly-typed configuration model which is being deserialized from an underlying provider/serializer. Then I'd like to have the returned instance from the serializer actually BE the current instance. However for e.g. DTO/PTO mapping etc., I expect the instance being copied.

Comment: So if you already have a reference to your instance and do not want a copy of it, why not simply use that reference instead?